# Не получается поставить иконку в окне customtkinter, В чём моя ошибка?

Tags: python, tkinter, pillow, customtkinter

Мой код:

```
import customtkinter as CTk
from PIL import Image

class App(CTk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry('800x500')
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.title('Main')
        self.logo = Image.open('img\\icon_ico.ico')
        self.iconphoto(False, self.logo)
        self.logo.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Artyom\PycharmProjects\generated-game-gpt3\ui.py", line 16, in <module>
    app = App()
          ^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Artyom\PycharmProjects\generated-game-gpt3\ui.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.iconphoto(False, self.logo)
  File "C:\Users\Artyom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2183, in wm_iconphoto
    self.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, *args)
_tkinter.TclError: can't use "<PIL.IcoImagePlugin.IcoImageFile image mode=RGBA size=256x256 at 0x1833DFF5550>" as iconphoto: not a photo image
```

Comment: В ошибке написано, что передан не photo image. Значит надо передать `PhotoImage`, например `self.photo_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.logo)` `self.iconphoto(False, self.photo_image)`

Comment: @insolor. Получается такая же ошибка: `can't use "<PIL.IcoImagePlugin.IcoImageFile image mode=RGBA size=256x256 at 0x2205AE31710>" as iconphoto: not a photo image`

Comment: Если та же ошибка, значит вы в строке `self.iconphoto(False, self.logo)` не поменяли self.logo на self.photo_image

Comment: @insolor. Сильно извиняюсь и вправду не заметил. Только новая иконка не появляется, не знаю это может из-за того что я использую customtkinter?

Comment: По идее не должно влиять. Возможно PhotoImage как поле объекта self не сохранили, тогда сборщик мусора мог удалить. Но это скорее догадка

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение на свой вопрос, вместо обычного добавления (как в tkinter) иконки нужно сделать так:

```
root.after(201, lambda :root.iconbitmap('C:\\Users\\...\\filename.ico'))
```

Источник - https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/discussions/1099

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: В этом треде автор библиотеки [пишет](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/discussions/1099#discussioncomment-4758323), что на актуальной версии с этим не должно быть никаких проблем. Также см. https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/issues/1125. Попробуйте просто обновить CustomTkinter у себя.

Comment: @insolor. У меня последняя, хз почему так происходит. Ну раз работает - то и фиг с ней.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin. Поправил

Comment: Ну может опять что-то сломали. Попробуйте аналогичный код на чистом tkinter переписать, будет такая проблема?

Comment: @insolor. Спасибо. Мне уже не нужно, мне этого костыля хватает